# Create Dynamic Controls using MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to create dynamic fields (textbox,combo) based on the entries in an XML file

I will read the ATTRIBUTES XML tag and must create the type of control and add validations to it. Can someone say how to use MVC3 to create dynamic controls, becos i cannot have different class for models as the XML file will change for each screen and i will have one screen which will generate this page for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you can create your own html helper functions to do that. There are built-in helpers such as `html.TextBoxFor(x => x.id)`. So you might write your own `html.RenderFor( () => xmlDocumentBindedToyYourView )`

And your controller for example

```
public ActionResult render()
{
   XMLDocument xdoc ; // do your xml doc reading....
   return View(xdoc);
}
```